# Javascript regex matching <SVG> tags with optional attribute viewBox

Tags: javascript, tags, regex-group

I'm trying to match `<svg>` tag with optional attribute **viewBox** and to extract its value. I want to match all of the following variations of `<svg>` tag:

```
<svg width="28" height="32" viewBox="0 0 28 32">
<!-- svg content must be grouped -->
</svg>


<svg viewBox="0 0 28 32">
<!-- svg content must be grouped -->
</svg>

<svg width="28" height="32" viewBox="0 0 28 32">
<!-- svg content must be grouped -->
</svg>

<svg>
<!-- svg content must be grouped -->
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 28 32" width="28" height="32">
<!-- svg content must be grouped -->
</svg>
```

here, **width** and **height** and **viewBox** are *optionals* and value of viewBox attribute and svg content must be *grouped*.

the following regex works in case that viewBox is required attribute:

```
/<svg\b[^>]*\s*(viewBox=\"(\b[^"]*)\").*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/svg>/
```

please see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/K7gTqp/1)

[image]

but when I make **viewBox** optional group, there is no matched group (note **?** symbol after parentheses):

```
/<svg\b[^>]*\s*(viewBox=\"(\b[^"]*)\")?.*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/svg>/
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind another group, you can use an alternation for the part without the viewBox attribute `<svg\b[^>]*\s*(viewBox="(\b[^"]*)").*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/svg>|<svg>([\s\S]*?)<\/svg>` https://regex101.com/r/CTaCvi/1 In the code you can then check for the existence of group 4 (which is the extra group after the `|`) But it might be easier to use a parser to get the values if available.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, but it not solve my problem. I need a general regex code.

Answer (score 1):

At end it solved by following regex:

```
<svg\b[^>]*?(?:viewBox=\"(\b[^"]*)\")?>([\s\S]*?)<\/svg>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BC6FpH/1)